# PyQt5: create multiple views with designer and connect them in one app

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I have completed a simple app in PyQt5, where I did design the UI in QT designer, converted in py code with `pyuic5`and ran it via python interpreter.

Now I would like to add another UI view, although I am not familiar with PyQt5, and most of the tutorial I found are only mentioning one view.
If I was using Visual Studio for example, I could create a new form, and use show and hide methods to display them, when I press a button for example, but I am not sure how to do the same with PyQt5.

Converted code from `pyuic5` include also the `if __name__ == "__main__"` function, which create the instance and run the app, so is it enough to just take anything above it, to get the UI data only? And how do I create a view from that, so I can show and hide it as needed? Thanks.

**EDIT**:
Got a bit further, since I found a different way to load `UI` files. Seems that PyQt has a method that is able to load a UI file directly, instead of convert it in python code. This means that I can create a class that is a subclass of the type of window that I am using (example: `QApplication`, `QMainWindow`, `QWidget` and so on), and I can access that object as if it was a form in Visual Studio.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.uic import loadUI

class UIObject(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(UIObject, self).__init__()
        loadUI('mainapp.ui', self)
        self.mybutton1.clicked.connect(self.printhello)

    def printhello():
        print("hello")

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainview = UIObject()
mainview.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This will load the UI file and show it on screen; I assume that I can use the same construct to load multiple `ui` files and show then or hide them as I do in Visual studio? Seems straightforward but not knowing much about QT or PyQT, I am not sure why this way to handle `ui` files is not more commonly advertised in tutorials; I found it by chance while reading the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution, mixing up various answers and posts from different forums.

You create a first class as `QMainWindow`, in the `__init__` you use `loadUi` to load the QT designer file. Then you create a second class, which is the one that hold your second form/view, and in the `__init__` you pass as parameter the parent view (your first class, or whatever other you may need); so you can hide the main view and show the second view when clicking a button. When you close the secondary view, the previous view will show up again.

You can add as many different windows you want; the trick is to always pass the parent on each of them and remember to show/hide them accordingly. Much more complex than Visual Studio forms, but it is doable.

```
class FirstForm(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(FirstForm, self).__init__()
        loadUi('firstform.ui', self)
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.openOtherForm)

    def openOtherForm(self):
        self.hide()
        otherview = SecondForm(self)
        otherview.show()

class SecondForm(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SecondForm, self).__init__(parent)
        loadUi('secondform.ui', self)
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.goBackToOtherForm)

    def openOtherForm(self):
        self.parent().show()
        self.close()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main = FirstForm()
main.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```